# Linq to xml portion of XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am using Linq to XML to save a List into XML string.

The xml string I am trying to get:

```
<people>
<name>xxx</name>
<age>23</age>
</people>
<people>
<name>yyy</name>
<age>25</age>
</people>
```

C# code:

```
List<Peoples> peopleList = new List<Peoples>(); 
peopleList.Add(new Peoples() { Name = "xxx", Age = 23 });
peopleList.Add(new Peoples() { Name = "yyy", Age = 25 });
var people (from item in peopleList
select new XElement("people",
                                new XAttribute("name", item.Name),
                                new XAttribute("age", item.Age)
                            ));
```

How can I convert `var people` into `XML string`?

Thank you.

---

Edited :

What I can think of is to add a root element  into the xml, and replace  and   with empty string.

---

Jignesh Thakker solution works:

```
string str = people.Select(x => x.ToString()).Aggregate(String.Concat);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two solution by which you can get XML string.

**Solution 1:** To Get XMl string you need put XmlElement in XDocument object. Try with,

```
  List<Peoples> peopleList = new List<Peoples>(); 
  peopleList.Add(new Peoples() { Name = "xxx", Age = 23 });
  peopleList.Add(new Peoples() { Name = "yyy", Age = 25 });
  var people =  (from item in peopleList
  select new XElement("people",
                            new XElement("name", item.Name),
                            new XElement("age", item.Age)
                        ));

  XElement root = new XElement("Peoples");
  root.Add(people);
  XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(
                         new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
                         root);
  string str = xDoc.ToString();
```

you need root element to get Xml string.

**OUTPUT:**

```
<Peoples>
  <people>
    <name>xxx</name>
    <age>23</age>
  </people>
  <people>
    <name>yyy</name>
    <age>25</age>
  </people>
</Peoples>
```

Here Name & Age consider as XElement. As your code in question you mentioned `XAttribute`. Try with below code if you want to consider Name & age as `XAttribute`.

```
   List<Peoples> peopleList = new List<Peoples>(); 
   peopleList.Add(new Peoples() { Name = "xxx", Age = 23 });
   peopleList.Add(new Peoples() { Name = "yyy", Age = 25 });
   var people =  (from item in peopleList
                           select new XElement("people",
                            new XAttribute("name", item.Name),
                            new XAttribute("age", item.Age)
                        ));

    XElement root = new XElement("Peoples");
    root.Add(people);
    XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(
                         new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
                         root);


    string str = xDoc.ToString();
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<Peoples>
  <people name="xxx" age="23" />
  <people name="yyy" age="25" />
</Peoples>
```

**Solution 2:** Try with below if you want Xml string from `List<XElement>`:

```
string str = people.Select(x => x.ToString()).Aggregate(String.Concat);
```

If XElement used for name & age then **OUTPUT:**

```
  <people>
    <name>xxx</name>
    <age>23</age>
  </people>
  <people>
    <name>yyy</name>
    <age>25</age>
  </people>
```

IF XAttribute used for name & age then **OUTPUT:**

```
  <people name="xxx" age="23" />
  <people name="yyy" age="25" />
```

Hope It should work. Solution 2 is most appropriate for what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You want the "name" and "age" to be elements, not attributes. Since you have no top element in your desired output. It is the sequential output of two elements.

```
void Main()
{
    List<Peoples> peopleList = new List<Peoples>(); 
    peopleList.Add(new Peoples() { Name = "xxx", Age = 23 });
    peopleList.Add(new Peoples() { Name = "yyy", Age = 25 });
    var people =(from item in peopleList
    select new XElement("people",
                                    new XElement("name", item.Name),
                                    new XElement("age", item.Age)
                                ));
    Console.WriteLine (people.First());
    Console.WriteLine (people.Last());
}

class Peoples
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

EDIT#1: I want to emphasize that your desired output is not a single xml output. If I add a root object, you get pretty close. Try this:

```
XElement root = new XElement("root");
foreach (var item in peopleList)
{
    root.Add(new XElement("people",
                                new XElement("name", item.Name),
                                new XElement("age", item.Age)
                            ));         
}
Console.WriteLine (root.ToString());
```

Comment: How do I convert var people into xml string?

Comment: Have you tried running it? It is the string representation of an XElement type. Use ToString() if you want to be explicit.

Comment: It gives me System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[Model.SalesItem,System.Xml.Linq.XElement], but trxTtems.First() will give me a string.

Comment: What if I have more then two items?

Comment: Well, you can foreach over it. It is important that you understand that your desired output is not a single XML output because you don't have a single root object. See edit#1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will give you what you need

```
List<Peoples> peopleList = new List<Peoples>();
            peopleList.Add(new Peoples() { Name = "xxx", Age = 23 });
            peopleList.Add(new Peoples() { Name = "yyy", Age = 25 });

            var people = new XElement("Peoples", peopleList.Select(p => 
                                                             new XElement("people",
                                                                          new XAttribute("name", p.Name),
                                                                          new XAttribute("age", p.Age)
                                                                 ))).ToString();
```

This would produce the following XML

```
<Peoples>
  <people name="xxx" age="23" />
  <people name="yyy" age="25" />
</Peoples>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> peopleList = new List<Person>(); 
        peopleList.Add(new Person() { Name = "xxx", Age = 23 });
        peopleList.Add(new Person() { Name = "yyy", Age = 25 });

        XElement xmlDoc = new XElement("people", from p in peopleList
                                                 select new XElement("person",
                                                                     new XElement("name", p.Name),
                                                                     new XElement("age", p.Age)));

        Console.WriteLine(xmlDoc.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Will produce:

```
<people>
  <person>
    <name>xxx</name>
    <age>23</age>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>yyy</name>
    <age>25</age>
  </person>
</people>
```